# TFLearn import error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have installed tensorflow with docker in my windows machine. I am opening the tensorflow with powershell

> docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow

It's opening on a ipython notebook. But when I want to import

> import tflearn
>   ImportError: No module named tflearn.

After that I have installed tflearn with

> pip install tflearn

But getting still same error. What is the problem anyone know that?

Comment: did you install in the same shell? different python distributions? the pip install did not go well?

Comment: yeah that ones different python distribions. It's because of tensorflow doesnt working without ipython notebook. How can i install tflearn inipython notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are having trouble installing TFLearn inside tensorflow docker container. In order to do that you can simply launch a new terminal from the Ipython Notebook interface and install your package there using pip.
[image]

To install TFLearn, use the same command that you used `pip install tflearn`.
If pip is not installed by default, you can do that by `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.